# How do I get user to input two last names and have Javascript spit out which one comes first alphabetically?

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment for Javascript class. The basis of the assignment is to use the if/else if statements to set up the script. I've read and re-read the assignment and I don't understand how to get the names (user input) in alphabetical ordering. Please help!My instructor and book are useless! Here are the instructions:

Write the JavaScript code in one HTML document using IF, and IF/Else statements for the following three situations. For each one make sure to write comments for each section.

B. Check for the alphabetical order of names.

(See ASCII table at http://www.asciitable.com/ to confirm)

Variable declarations section
1. Declare a variable that holds a person’s last name.
2. Declare a variable that holds a second person’s last name.

Assignments section
3. Ask the user to enter their last name.
4. Ask the user to enter the last name of a friend.

Logic and Output section
5. Use only variables in your logic.
6. Determine which name is first in the ascending sequence of the alphabet.
7. Display the message “Your last name is before/after mine in the alphabet.”

Testing: Try names that have the same first letter. Compare names where one begins with a small letter and the other a capital letter. Compare names that are close with one letter different like: Anderson and Andersen.

My code thus far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Variable declarations

            var userLast1;          
            var userLast2;

       // Assignments

        userLast1 = prompt("Please enter your last name.");
        userLast2 = prompt("Please enter the last name of a friend.");

       // Calculations & output

       if (userLast1 > userLast2)
       {
       alert("Your last name comes before your friend's in the alphabet.");
       }
       else if (userLast2 > userLast1)
       {
       alert("Your friend's last name comes before your's in the alphabet.");
       }
       else
       {
       alert("You and your friend have the same last name.");
       }


    </script>
```

Comment: Why did you choose to use parseFloat? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: @Stefano - its marked homework so don't give answer, just help OP towards solution. You want to really educate them on why they are using certain functions and making certain decisions.

Comment: why? what do you mean? I don't understand what I'm doing and need help. Why is that bad?

Comment: Followup question, if you were going to figure out whether two words came before or after one another, how would you do it? Often it helps to write out in plain english what you want to happen before actually trying to change that into code.

Comment: I don't need someone to code the whole answer, I just don't understand how to set up the if/else if so the output gives the user the last name in alphabetical order.

Comment: I may not be too well versed in the language of programming assignments, but what the... does "Use only variables in your logic" mean?

Comment: Do you know what a floating point number is? Take a look at that link I gave you. parseFloat converts a string to a number. So your code says - take whatever user entered and turn it into a number.

Comment: I don't even know what the parsefloat does. My instructor uses it and told us to use it when prompting for info. I'm a web design student, and HAVE to take JavaScript because my degree lightly touches into web development. The teacher NEVER clarifies anything. Everyone in the class is always confused. The assignments do not match the info given in the books, hence the mass confusion on my part. I'm assuming the use variable part means she doesnt want anything else besides the declared variables used in the if/else if statement

Comment: so i should take out parsefloat since i'm dealing with names not numbers?

Comment: @mrtsherman It was Bruno's edit to add the "homework" tag, I had written my, admittedly too short, comment before that. Removed my comment since unuseful now. Stephanie, I understand your teacher is not looking very helpful and apparently you are not really fond of programming, but I meant you should still make an effort :)

Comment: no i don't expect it fully solved just need help with the ASCII part and how to get the output alphabatized in an if/else if format..you have to understand i've only studied JavaScript for 3 weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the strings with `<` and friends.  All you need to do is (in pseudocode):

```
if str1 is less than str2
    output "first string is less than second string"
else
    output "second string is less than first string"
```

The only gotcha here is that `"B"<"a"` returns true, which may be intended behavior.

As far as your code is concerned, you do not want to use parseFloat.  Think about (or google) what parseFloat does.  What do you think will happen when you pass someone's last name (that doesn't include any digits) into parseFloat, and is that the behavior you want?

If you need help with the syntax of `if` statements, here is an example:

```
if (1 < 2) {
    alert("1 is less than 2.  Who knew?");
} else {
    alert("This really should not be reached, since 1 is less than 2");
}
```

Comment: but how do i do that with letters instead of numbers? i'm workin with names not numbers!

Comment: you can compare letters the same way as numbers.  `"asdf" < "bsdf"` returns true.

Comment: I believe you want `<`, not `>`.  Lower letters correspond to the beginning of the alphabet, so the smallest name comes first in alphabetical order.  Other than that, your code looks good.  Make this one fix, and I think that your code should run correctly.

Comment: @StephanieKay: Be aware that even though it's not entirely clear from the assignment (but which part of it is...?), it's likely it wants you to ignore the case of the letters - which means that "B" should come after "a". Test your code and make sure that's the case, because like Retief says, `"B"<"a"` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take up the comparison part here.

try the following:

```
if ("a"<"b") { 
    alert("a comes before b")
} else {
    alert("b comes before a")
}
```

Basically in javascript you can compare strings simply using "<" and ">". They will be compared using the value of each character, one after the other.

Forget the `parseFloat` in your example, and start experimenting with this simple comparison!

Comment: right, i get that part, the format of the if/else if.. it's just converting the names into ASCII or whatever..that's the part I don't get how to do.

Comment: `prompt` gives you a string, which can be compared with `<`.  This comparison always uses ASCII ordering.  `prompt("first name") < prompt("second name")` is a perfectly valid expression that will prompt the user for two names and return true if the first name is strictly less than the next name (if they are equal, it will return false).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the sort method?

```
var names = new Array();
names.push(prompt("Please enter your last name."));
names.push(prompt("Please enter the last name of a friend."));

document.write(names.sort());
```

Comment: no, it has to be in if/else if format. her directions say specifically "Write the JavaScript code in one HTML document using IF, and IF/Else statements for the following situations." :(

Comment: Just hand my answer in and tell her you used the most effective method instead of her useless one.

Comment: I wish..if only you knew her. She was the head web administrator for a huge corporation, got a master's and decided in her late 50's she'd rather teach..let's just say she doesn't know how. she gives assignments and expects them done. she doesn't get we need to be taught Javascript first..  It's only the third week of school and she just throws us in the deep end. I have no programming experience whatsoever besides xhtml.

Comment: That does not sound ideal. At least you came to the right place for help.

Comment: I know..i've been working on this since 11am. I'm about to cry i've looked through my book, rewatched her tutorials, looked through example code. She is the worst college instructor I've had thus far..this is an intro course.

Answer (score 0):

The sort method is great *only* if you can use external functions like those. If not...

parseFloat is going to literally give you a number back, sure, but it doesn't work on strings other than those with leading numbers, such as "10 is here", or "23.33 33". So, a good way to accomplish this is to get the name (the string), and then compare each character ascii code with .charCodeAt(). Go through for-loops like that, and whenever you find the higher/lower, break from the loop (you should probably use a separate variable to hold the info of which one was earlier in the order, or append it to an array you have already created).

Retief's answer is easier and more efficient.